# Flutter - How should be bloc communications in complex UI?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, bloc

I want some advice on a topic which I'm curious about. What is the best way and best practice? I tried to draw a UI about this topic. I am using the [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package.

**Scenario**: I have a list as shown in the picture and there are score buttons at the bottom. Buttons are not active without making a selection in the list. Buttons are active when I select an item from the list. When I press the score button, a score is written to the selected element in the list and the score buttons become inactive again.

This UI looks simple, but my problem is with a more complicated UI. ***So I will definitely use more than one bloc on a screen.***

I wonder how do I get this communication between the blocs in the best way? Should I create a parent block on a top layer?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should have a single bloc which will control the whole screen.
On your bloc state you could have a property which holds the selected item(or its index - really up to you here). Your point buttons will be enabled/disabled based on this prop through a `BlocBuilder`.
On a point button tap you just add an event like `PointsAssigned(amount: 50)` or `FiftyPointsAssigned()` - again up to you. This event will be mapped to a state where the points are attached to the selected item and will rebuild the UI through a `BlocBuilder` so your change will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple bloc can be used in same context. You can use `MultiBlocProvider` from `flutter_bloc`
Then, you can access both bloc data and communicate whatever you defined in the Bloc.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MultiBlocProvider(
            providers: [
              BlocProvider<TodoBloc>(create: (BuildContext context) => TodoBloc()),
              BlocProvider<PointBloc>(
                  create: (BuildContext context) => PointBloc()),
            ],
            child: Scaffold(
                        ......
                   ),
          );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to explain without knowing how your current codes look like. You don't really need additional bloc. Your Todo instance could have some sort of bool property `onSelected`.

```
Todo(
  final String name;
  final int point;
  final bool onSelected;

  Todo(this.name, this.point, this.onSelected);
)
```